# Deriving Topographic Information from Geotagged Photos?

Tags: elevation, geotag, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, gmt

I wish to extract elevation data from geotagged photos?

I have worked with DEM's and the open source CLI program: GMT for my graduate studies. I own a DJI Phantom 3 and used the trial version of Drone Deploy.

They are able to take geotagged jpg photos and create elevation data from it but how is this possible?

In the trial version they do not allow direct download of raw elevation data, but they do supply a Geotiff of the survey area, and using GMT I can convert the geotiff to netCDF file where then I can plot it again. However the elevation data isn't accurate as it would be on the DroneDeploy website itself.

Therefore, I am forced to work my ways backwards to find how to extract elevation data from geotagged jpgs.

Comment: Welcom to the forum @user98409! Your question is rather broad. It will help if you rephrase it more to the point and include the exact steps that you took to get to the elevation data. Try to avoid asking for general 'advice' but focus on one specific thing that you want to achieve. Also, very important, stick to only 1 question per post. 
All these things will greatly enhance the possibility of getting useful answers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Have a look at the Exif Tags of your image, it's probably there. If not obviously visible, look inside the "maker note" tag

Comment: They use SfM Structure from Motion to extract a point cloud from overlapping photos. A point cloud is, well, a cloud of points in X, Y and Z. Look for Visual SfM and give it a test run and read its documentation to get a better understanding of the concept.